# "Expected “,” but found property error using Apple Script

Tags: macos, applescript

I using Apple script to get the required details from Microsoft outlook. Its totally working fine on the Mountian Lion OsX(10.8.3) but when i use the same script its failing and throwing me the error ""Expected “,” but found property".

Below is the Apple Script which i am using.

```
on encodeXML(s)
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "&"
         set components to every text item of s
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "&amp;"
         set s to components as string
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "<"
             set components to every text item of s
             set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "&lt;"
             set s to components as string

             set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ">"
             set components to every text item of s
             set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "&gt;"
             set s to components as string

             set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\""
             set components to every text item of s
             set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "&quot;"
             set s to components as string

             set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "'"
             set components to every text item of s
             set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "&apos;"
             set s to components as string
             set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
             return s
         end encodeXML

         on meetingNumber(s)
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "Meeting Number:"
         set components to every text item of s
         if (count of components) is less than 2 then
         return ""
         end if
         set s to second text item of components
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "To join"
         set components to every text item of s
         set s to first text item of components
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "<"
         set components to every text item of s
         set s to first text item of components
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "&"
         set components to every text item of s
         set s to first text item of components
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "----"
         set components to every text item of s
         set s to first text item of components
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
         set components to every text item of s
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
         return components as string
         end meetingNumber

         on trimContents(s)
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "Meeting Number:"
         set components to every text item of s
         if (count of components) is less than 2 then
         return ""
         end if
         set s to second text item of components
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "To join"
         set components to every text item of s
         set s to first text item of components
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "<"
         set components to every text item of s
         set s to first text item of components
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "&"
         set components to every text item of s
         set s to first text item of components
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "----"
         set components to every text item of s
         set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
         return "Meeting Number: " & first text item of components
         end trimContents

         on getEventKeys(theEvent)
         set r to ""
         tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
         set r to r & "    <wxp:meeting>
         "
         set r to (r & "        <wxp:appID>" & id of theEvent as string) & "</wxp:appID>
         "
         set t to (content of theEvent as string)
         set t to my trimContents(t)
         set r to (r & "        <wxp:content>" & my encodeXML(t)) & "</wxp:content>
         "
         set r to r & "    </wxp:meeting>
         "
         end tell
         return r
         end getEventKeys

         on getEvent(theEvent)
         set retVal to ""
         tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set retVal to retVal & "<wxp:meeting>"
    set retVal to (retVal & "<wxp:subject>" & my encodeXML(subject of theEvent as string)) & "</wxp:subject>"
    set retVal to (retVal & "<wxp:organizer>" & organizer of theEvent as string) & "</wxp:organizer>"
    set retVal to (retVal & "<wxp:startDate>" & start time of theEvent as string) & "</wxp:startDate>"
    set retVal to (retVal & "<wxp:endDate>" & end time of theEvent as string) & "</wxp:endDate>"
    set retVal to (retVal & "<wxp:appID>" & ID of theEvent as string) & "</wxp:appID> "
         set outType to ""
         if (is recurring of theEvent) then
         set recur to recurrence of theEvent
         set recurType to recurrence type of recur as string
         if recurType is "daily" then
         set outType to "DAILY"
         else if recurType is "weekly" then
         set outType to "WEEKLY"
         else if recurType is "absolute monthly" or recurType is "relative monthly" then
         set outType to "MONTHLY"
         else if recurType is "absolute yearly" or recurType is "relative yearly" then
         set outType to "YEARLY"
         end if
         set retVal to retVal & "<wxp:repeatType>" & outType & "</wxp:repeatType>
         "
         set retVal to retVal & "<wxp:interval>" & occurrence interval of recur & "</wxp:interval>
         "
         if end type of end date of recur as string is "end numbered type" then
         set retVal to retVal & "<wxp:afterMeetingNumber>" & data of end date of recur & "</wxp:afterMeetingNumber>
         "
         else if end type of end date of recur as string is "end date type" then
         set retVal to (retVal & "<wxp:expirationDate>" & data of end date of recur as string) & "</wxp:expirationDate>
         "
         end if
         if recurType is "relative monthly" then
         set retVal to retVal & "<wxp:weekInMonth>" & ordinal of recur & "</wxp:weekInMonth>"
         end if
         if recurType is "weekly" or recurType is "relative monthly" then
         set bitmap to 0
         if sunday of days of week of recur then
         set bitmap to bitmap + 1
         end if
         if monday of days of week of recur then
         set bitmap to bitmap + 2
         end if
         if tuesday of days of week of recur then
         set bitmap to bitmap + 4
         end if
         if wednesday of days of week of recur then
         set bitmap to bitmap + 8
         end if
         if thursday of days of week of recur then
         set bitmap to bitmap + 16
         end if
         if friday of days of week of recur then
         set bitmap to bitmap + 32
         end if
         if saturday of days of week of recur then
         set bitmap to bitmap + 64
         end if
         set retVal to retVal & "<wxp:dayInWeek>" & bitmap & "</wxp:dayInWeek>
         "
         end if
         else
         set retVal to retVal & "<wxp:repeatType></wxp:repeatType>
         "
         end if

         if (has reminder of theEvent) then
         set retVal to (retVal & "        <wxp:reminder>" & reminder time of theEvent as string) & "</wxp:reminder>
         "
         end if
         --set attendees to attendee of theEvent
         set retVal to retVal & "        <wxp:attendees>
         "
         repeat with theAttendee in required attendee of theEvent
         set retVal to retVal & my writeAttendee(theAttendee, "REQUIRED")
         end repeat
         repeat with theAttendee in optional attendee of theEvent
         set retVal to retVal & my writeAttendee(theAttendee, "OPTIONAL")
         end repeat
         repeat with theAttendee in resource attendee of theEvent
         set retVal to retVal & my writeAttendee(theAttendee, "RESOURCE")
         end repeat
         set retVal to retVal & "        </wxp:attendees>
         "
         set retVal to (retVal & "        <wxp:content>" & my encodeXML(content of theEvent as string)) & "</wxp:content>
         "
         set retVal to retVal & "    </wxp:meeting>
         "
         end tell
         return retVal

         end getEvent

         on writeAttendee(theAttendee, theType)
         tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
         set retVal to ""
         if (status of theAttendee as string) is not "declined" then
         set em to email address of theAttendee
         set retVal to retVal & "            <wxp:attendee>
         "
         try
         set retVal to (retVal & "                <wxp:name>" & my encodeXML(name of em as string)) & "</wxp:name>
         "
         end try
         set retVal to (retVal & "                <wxp:ID>" & address of em as string) & "</wxp:ID>
         "
         set retVal to retVal & "                <wxp:type>" & theType & "</wxp:type>
         "
         set retVal to retVal & "            </wxp:attendee>
         "
         end if
         return retVal
         end tell
         end writeAttendee
```

Can some on please look into it and let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks In Advance.

---

Ravi Kishore.

Comment: Please clarify what OS it's not working in (i.e, other than 10.8.3) Also can you demonstrate how you are calling it as this is just a collection of functions.

Comment: ITs not working only on 10.9.x or higher versions. I am calling the above apple script on outlook to capture the meeting details.

Comment: Why is the Q tagged with "objective-c" and "cocoa"?

Answer (score 2):

The line `set em to email address of theAttendee` lies outside the `tell application "Microsoft Outlook"` block and so AppleScript does not understand the term `email address`.  Move this statement inside a `tell application "Microsoft Outlook"` block and you should be okay.

Comment: Thanks Mark.I will try to do that because the apple script which i am using works perfectly on 10.8.5